# Calculus- Differentials and multivariable functions

Tags: calculus, functional-analysis, multivariable-calculus

Find a differential of second order of a function $u=f(x,y)$ with continuous partial derivatives up to third order at least.
Hint: Take a look at $du$ as a function of the variables $x$, $y$, $dx$, $dy$: 
$du= F(x,y,dx,dy)=u_xdx +u_ydy$.

Can someone please explain me what should I do in this question?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is stated in a rather old-fashioned language. The "second differential" is probably the second derivative. It should be well-known that the second derivative is represented (in local coordinates) by the Hessian matrix
$$
f''(x,y) =
\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2} &\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x \partial y} \\
\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial y \partial x} &\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial y^2}
\end{pmatrix}.
$$
Its action is therefore
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
dx &dy
\end{pmatrix}^T
\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2} &\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x \partial y} \\
\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial y \partial x} &\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial y^2}
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
dx \\
dy
\end{pmatrix}
$$

Comment: Thanks ! But I still can't figure out what should I do...
What does it mean to find a differential that satisfies the above conditions? 

Hope you'll be able to help me abit further

Thanks !

Comment: As I said, I think it's just the differential of the differential.